# Put text in UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawrect, quartz-2d

Within my app, I use drawRect to draw some text within a UIImage. It writes multiple things in multiple places.. Later, I try to erase some of the text by using

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);

CGPoint daPoint = CGPointMake(second.x + 20, second.y + 20);

NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0],
                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName:   [UIColor clearColor] };

[textString drawAtPoint:daPoint withAttributes:textAttributes];
```

This works almost perfectly, except there is a small thin stroke left over from the text. I use the same code to draw the text, as I do to erase, except when i'm drawing I use `kCGBlendModeNormal`. How would I get rid of it completely? Can I draw a box and fill it using kCGBlendModeClear? This is what it looks like currently before erasing:

[image]

After erasing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get the bounding rect of the text and then call `CGContextClearRect` and then fill with the background color if you think that "erasing" the text is really necessary. If you simply "redraw" your rect, that might be another way to solve this problem.

Here's how to get that bounding box for clearing:

```
CGSize textSize = [textString sizeWithAttributes:textAttributes];
CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(daPoint.x, daPoint.y, textSize.width, textSize.height);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I get the bounding rect of the text? The text is stored in a dictionary, and i'm just drawing it, I don't have it as an object? If you could be a little more specific i'll accept your answer!

Comment: I've updated the answer on how to get the bounding rect. Let me know if you have any other questions about my answer.